# +++LOG: entry corrupt or truncated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-fragments

I constantly get the following message from logcat:

```
+++ LOG: entry corrupt or truncated
```

My code in Fragment class:

```
...
private String myVar;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   myVar = getResponse();

   okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

      myLogMsg(); //log messages on logcat
       }
    });
}

private void myLogMsg(){
    Log.v("My Log", myVar);
}
```

Why I got the message "**+++LOG: entry corrupt or truncated**" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

test code with

```
Log.v("My Log", "test test log");
```

because it may be possible `myVar` contain much amount of data.so `Log.v(`) is probably not meant to print that much amount of text.

Comment: i still get the same msg in log cat even i tried to use Log.e() also.... Any help

Comment: got answer as in onCreate() method i was trying to access the value of EditText before it is provided on UI by user becoz onCreate() just make the EditText, but value is entered only after creation of EditText. i just retrieved the value in another function other than onCreate().